# Using outputs terraform files in other terraform files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am new to terraform and have a few questions. Is there a way in terraform, to use the outputs of a module, in another tf file, **WITHOUT** having a "main" terraform file, or defining both modules in the same file?

For example, this is a project structure:

```
project/
├── networking
│   ├── init.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   ├── variables.tf
│   └── vpc.tf
├── prd-project-1
│   ├── init.tf
│   ├── instances.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
├── prd-project-2
│   ├── init.tf
│   ├── instances.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
├── prd-project-3
│   ├── init.tf
│   ├── instances.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
├── test
│   ├── init.tf
│   ├── instances.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
```

`vpc.tf` would create a VPC and subnets.
`instances.tf` would create EC2 instances, based on the vpc-id and subnets created previously in `vpc.tf`. I want to treat/manage these as two seperate actions. ie. First, I would run terraform to create the vpc and subnets, then later I might run terraform to create instances in prod/test for various projects. In this example, I would have only 1 VPC for test and 1 VPC for prod. I would not want a VPC per project (which I am again assuming TF might create if the `vpc.tf` module is referenced in one of the sub-projects).

Is it best practise to manage terraform code in this way? My concern is if eventually there are many projects needing EC2 instances, I don't want all of these in a single huge `main.tf`. I am thinking it is safer/cleaner to maintain these all seperately, as long as the vpc outputs can be referenced.  I also don't want my terraform plan/applies being slow and checking each and every resource from every project if I am standing up a new project.

The second part of my question is - consider the following code snippet:

```
module "main-vpc" {
  source     = "../modules/vpc"
  ENV        = "prod"
  AWS_REGION = var.AWS_REGION
}

module "instances" {
  source         = "../modules/instances"
  ENV            = "prod"
  VPC_ID         = module.main-vpc.vpc_id
  PUBLIC_SUBNETS = module.main-vpc.public_subnets
}
```

Is terraform smart enough to determine that a VPC was already created with an ENV = prod and would not try to recreate it if I called the same "main-vpc" module in another tf file/project?

I've read a few other posts here on stackoverflow, but they all allude that outputs from a module can only be referenced in another module within the same tf file.

Some other posts I've reviewed:

- [Using outputs from other tf files in terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62981799/using-outputs-from-other-tf-files-in-terraform)
- [Pass terraform output from one file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343976/pass-terraform-output-from-one-file-to-another)
- [Terraform module - output variable as input for another module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065536/terraform-module-output-variable-as-input-for-another-module)
- [Terraform structure for two aws accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56703203/terraform-structure-for-two-aws-accounts)

Comment: Sorry its not clear what you want to do. What's wrong with having main.tf?

Comment: If I have, for example, 100 projects. And I want to make a change for project 84, running terraform plan/apply is going to be a long/time consuming task as it needs to go through every project and check for changes. Instead, I would like to contain and deploy seperate projects, but reference outputs of other modules e.g. VPC ID and Subnet IDs.

Comment: I think you have to redesign your approach. You either have the project fully separated or you use terraform workspaces to sperate them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to have independent projects that can still access outputs from one another. So, for example, a project that spins up EC2 instances can refer to the subnets defined in the project that creates a VPC.

There are two ways to do this. First, you can use data sources to query the current deployment environment. For example, the following will look for the VPC with the `ENV` tag having a value of "prod" (assuming that I haven't made any typos):

```
data "aws_vpc" "prod" {
  tags = { "ENV": "prod" }
}
```

Second, you can use remote state (which is a good idea anyway, for security). Each project would write its outputs to a data store (S3 is common, but Terraform offers its own store), and they would be referenced by the others.

And while SO doesn't like links, I can't explain it better than the Terraform docs: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/state/backends.html

Comment: @Marcin - I think you wanted to reply to the OP?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This makes a lot of sense and perfectly answers my questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep your current folder structure, its best to add `main.tf` to each project:

```
project/
├── networking
│   ├── init.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   ├── variables.tf
│   └── vpc.tf
├── prd-project-1
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── init.tf
│   ├── instances.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
├── prd-project-2
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── init.tf
│   ├── instances.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
├── prd-project-3
│   ├── main.tf
│   ├── init.tf
│   ├── instances.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
├── test
│   ├── init.tf
│   ├── instances.tf
│   ├── terraform.tfvars
│   └── variables.tf
```

Then each `main.tf` would be something as follow:

```
module "main-vpc" {
  source     = "../networking"
  ENV        = "prod"
  AWS_REGION = var.AWS_REGION
}

module "instances" {
  source         = "../instances"
  ENV            = "prod"
  VPC_ID         = module.main-vpc.vpc_id
  PUBLIC_SUBNETS = module.main-vpc.public_subnets
}
```

This way you keep your project separate and **each project will have its own TF state file**.

> Is terraform smart enough to determine that a VPC was already created with an ENV

No its not. You would have to program your own logic for that. A common way is through a variable

```
variable "vpc_id" {
  default = ""
}
```

then if you do not explicitly specify the `vpc_id` for a given project, it would create new VPC. Otherwise, it would use `var.vpc_id` that you provide as an input parameter. Using [data sources](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/data-sources/index.html) you would then get other information for that VPC, such as its subnets.

Having this setup, you would `cd` to each project folder first, before deploying it, e.g.

```
cd ./prd-project-1
terraform apply
```